# How to force wget to skip links leading to parent elements?

Tags: bash, wget

Let's say I've got:

```
http://svnserver/repoid/appname/language/module/
```

I'm trying to download everything below **module** node, unfortunately page contains links to both - items below and items above in hierarchy (much like bash `ls -ltr` output). So when I use wget with recursive download option I end up with complete website (svn repository) downloaded and not only the module I need.

Is there any trick to prevent wget from following links that point to parent elements?

Comment: If it's an svn repository, why not use `svn export http://svnserver/repoid/appname/language/module/` ?

Comment: I don't have and I can't have svn on the remote machine :)

Comment: As mentioned below, you use the `-np` switch, but make sure to include a trailing slash if the URL ends with a directory instead of a file, otherwise the switch won’t work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `--no-parent` parameter.

From the output of `wget --help`

```
 -np, --no-parent                 don't ascend to the parent directory.
```

Comment: perfect, I was checking it before, but most probably made a typo. -np does work. thanks

Comment: Is there a way to skip creation of the parent directories as well? (everything above my module dir)

Comment: -p (--page-requisites) is useful with -np, since images are often in a different part of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

From `man wget`:

> -np
>
> --no-parent
>
> Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively.  This is a useful option, since it guarantees that only
>   the files below a certain hierarchy will be downloaded.